# How to read dataframe in rdd operations

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cartesian-product

Scenario
I have two string lists containing text file path, List a, List b. 
I want to to cartesian product of list a,b to achieve a cartesian dataframe comparison.

The way I am trying is first do cartesian product,
 transfer it to pairRdd and then on foreach apply operation.

```
 List<String> a = Lists.newList("/data/1.text",/data/2.text","/data/3.text");
 List<String> b = Lists.newList("/data/4.text",/data/5.text","/data/6.text");

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
List<Tuple2<String,String>> cartesian = cartesian(a,b);
jsc.parallelizePairs(cartesian).filter(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean>() {
        @Override public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, String> tup) throws Exception {
            Dataset<Row> text1 = spark.read().text(tup._1); <-- this throw NullPointerException
            Dataset<Row> text2 = spark.read().text(tup._2);
            return text1.first()==text2.first(); <-- this is an indicative function only
        });
```

Even I can use spark to do cartesian as

```
JavaRDD<Column> sourceRdd = jsc.parallelize(a);
JavaRDD<Column> allRdd = jsc.parallelize(b);

sourceRdd.cache().cartesian(allRdd).filter(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean>() {
        @Override public Boolean call(Tuple2<Column, Column> tup) throws Exception {
            Dataset<Row> text1 = spark.read().text(tup._1);  <-- same issue
            Dataset<Row> text2 = spark.read().text(tup._2);
            return text1.first()==text2.first();
        }
    });
```

Please suggest good approach to handle this.

Comment: there's no reason to do `jsc.parallelizePairs(cartesian)`. Iterate over the `cartesian` collection directly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understood your problem. Here is the sample for Cartesian using Spark and Java.

```
public class CartesianDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CartesianDemo").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    //list
    List<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    List<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList("ww", "xx", "yy", "zz");
    //RDD
    JavaRDD<String> rddOne = jsc.parallelize(listOne);
    JavaRDD<String> rddTwo = jsc.parallelize(listTwo);
    //Cartesian
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> cartesianRDD = rddOne.cartesian(rddTwo);
    //print
    cartesianRDD.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println("X=" + data._1() + " Y=" + data._2());
    });
    //stop
    jsc.stop();
    jsc.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew about cartesian and if you notice I already put that in example. The issue is running sparkSession.read() inside the foreach function.

Comment: That will not work and will throw NPE. You can find similar issues reported at SO. You can use Dataset.join method to get Cartesian and then you can call filter on that.